# Areas, Integrals and Antiderivatives question

Tags: calculus, integration

Taking a calculus II class, and the first week is review of Calculus I.. it's just been three years since I took calc I, so i'm sorry if this question is super simple.

Could someone please assist in what I need to do (step by step would be absolutely amazing) for question 4

[image]

(a)Graph  y = A(x)  for  1 ≤ x ≤ 5

(b)Estimate the values of  A(1), A(2), A(3), and A(4)

(c)Estimate the values of  A'(1), A'(2), A'(3), and A'(4)

[image: question 4]

Comment: What is your difficulty with this problem? Please share what you have tried, as it gives insight into what might be causing you trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) The integral of a straight line is a parabola, so before $x=3$, the graph should be a parabola. After $x=3$, if you split it up in $\int_1^3 f(t)\,\mathrm dt + \int_3^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt$, you’ll see that this is a constant plus the integral of a straight line. This is also a parabola (but a different one). If you know 3 points on a parabola, you can uniquely find the parabola, so just compute A(1), A(2), A(3) for the first parabola and A(3), A(4), A(5) for the second parabola (this is problem b).

(b) Remember that the integral from $1$ to $x$ is the area under the graph, and that the area of a right triangle is $\frac12ab$.

(c) The derivative of an integral is the original function, so you can just look at the graph.